How to set SSHD to listen at only IPv4?
current config (rebooot was also done)
root@ubi:~# grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 30000
root@ubi:~# 
root@ubi:~# grep ListenAddress /etc/ssh/sshd_config
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
root@ubi:~# 
root@ubi:~# netstat -tulpn|grep 30000
tcp6       0      0 :::30000                :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
root@ubi:~# 
root@ubi:~# ss -tulpn|grep 30000
tcp   LISTEN 0      4096               *:30000            *:*    users:(("sshd",pid=38048,fd=3),("systemd",pid=1,fd=251))
root@ubi:~# 
root@ubi:~# grep PRETTY_NAME= /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
root@ubi:~# 

Question: is this a bug? i set sshd to listen on only IPv4, why is it listening in IPv6?

You have to set:
AddressFamily inet
In your sshd_config too for IPV4 only
And restart your ssh server
systemctl restart sshd
You can also disable IPV6 on your server to.
Add this to the end of file;
/etc/sysctl.conf
# Disable IPV6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

and restart:
/sbin/sysctl -p

added AddressFamily inet and disabled ipv6 and reboooted, but netstat still says tcp6, LOL, but thanks

Some services or applications might use IPv6 or have IPv6-specific configurations that cause them to still use tcp6, even if IPv6 is disabled system-wide. check Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf if there are entrys. and as muru said set ListenStream= to empty

As can been seen from the process information, it's not ssh that's setting up the socket, but systemd, as is normal for socket-activated services. So you need to configure the systemd socket unit to change the port and listen addresses.
Run systemctl edit ssh.socket (or sshd.socket, depending on the distro), and add:
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:22

From man systemd.socket:
ListenStream=, ListenDatagram=, ListenSequentialPacket=

Specifies an address to listen on for a stream (SOCK_STREAM), datagram (SOCK_DGRAM), or sequential packet (SOCK_SEQPACKET) socket, respectively. The address can be written in various formats:
If the address starts with a slash ("/"), it is read as file system socket in the AF_UNIX socket family.
If the address starts with an at symbol ("@"), it is read as abstract namespace socket in the AF_UNIX family. The "@" is replaced with a NUL character before binding. For details, see unix(7).
If the address string is a single number, it is read as port number to listen on via IPv6. Depending on the value of BindIPv6Only= (see below) this might result in the service being available via both IPv6 and IPv4 (default) or just via IPv6.
If the address string is a string in the format "v.w.x.y:z", it is interpreted as IPv4 address v.w.x.y and port z.

The default is probably ListenStream=22, which results in "the service being available via both IPv6 and IPv4 (default)". These settings are additive, so you need to reset ListenStream by setting it to empty:

These options may be specified more than once, in which case incoming traffic on any of the sockets will trigger service activation, and all listed sockets will be passed to the service, regardless of whether there is incoming traffic on them or not. If the empty string is assigned to any of these options, the list of addresses to listen on is reset, all prior uses of any of these options will have no effect.


edited the socket, then reboooted, but netstat still says tcp6, LOL, but thanks

@peterK88 ah, yeah, the ListenStream setting needs to be reset. See updated answer.

There has been a recent change on this. Please see my answer at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1532434/855322
